# compile error in git: imap-send.c:1408: error: ‘CURLOPT_USERNAME’ undeclared

Tags: git, compiler-errors

I wanted to install git into a serve in which I was just an user without "sudo" access. So I cannot use `yum install git`.

I tried to download source code both from https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/ (v2.11.0.tar.gz) and from github (v2.3.0.zip).
When compiling the souce the error happened:

```
imap-send.c: In function ‘setup_curl’:
imap-send.c:1408: error: ‘CURLOPT_USERNAME’ undeclared (first use in this function)
imap-send.c:1408: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
imap-send.c:1408: error: for each function it appears in.)
imap-send.c:1409: error: ‘CURLOPT_PASSWORD’ undeclared (first use in this function)
imap-send.c:1434: error: ‘CURLOPT_USE_SSL’ undeclared (first use in this function)
imap-send.c:1434: error: ‘CURLUSESSL_TRY’ undeclared (first use in this function)
make: *** [imap-send.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

The two versions gave the same errors. I checked the source code from github and got the postion of the codes, but I could not understand why the error happened.

How should I isntall git into the server (CentOS) without administration access.

Comment: You may have to install a newer version of curl first.

Comment: @melpomene Hi, my curl version is `curl 7.49.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.49.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2j zlib/1.2.8`. The version isn't too old, is it?

Comment: By "curl" I mean the libcurl (the curl library) and specifically its headers (`curlver.h` should contain the relevant version number(s)).

Answer (score 6):

I solved the problem by myself.

It was obvious that the problem was caused by curl.

1. Use `which curl` to see the right path of curl. In my server, It was:
   `/home/myname/Programs/Anaconda/bin/curl` So it was anaconda that changed my curl.
2. To set the curl path by
   `git-2.11.0 $ ./configure --with-curl=$/home/myname/Programs/Anaconda/bin/curl`
   before
   `git-2.11.0 $ make prefix=/home/myname/path/to/install all`
   and then
   `git-2.11.0 $ make install prefix=/home/myname/path/to/install DESTDIR=/home/myname/path/to/install`